# how to pass a value in a URL using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, real-time

I am trying to do a real-time bidding system to bid jobs.I did the real-time code and I can view the jobs in a table. In each row there is a link when I click on it it should take me to another page with the id value in the url. My problem is when a I click on Apply link it didn't take me to the second page.
Anyone can help me please?

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
done();
   });

 function done(){
 setTimeout(function(){
updates();
 done();

},500   );
 }

 function updates(){

   $.getJSON("jobs_by_company_PHP.php", function(data){

$(".text_2").empty();
$("#subbu").empty();

$.each(data.result,function(){ 

     $(".text_2").append("<style>table, td, th {    border: 1px solid #ddd;
   text-align: left; width:400px;  font-size: 30px;}"+
               "     table {"+
            "  border-collapse: collapse;"+
            "  width: 170%; "+
             "   font-size: 30px;  "+
             "margin-left:0px;"+
         " } "+

        "  th, td {"+
        "width:400px;"+
         "     padding: 15px;  "+
          "      font-size: 30px;   "+
         " }      "+



     "</style> <table  summary='Summary Here' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>" +
     "<thead>" +
        "<th>  ID </th>"  +
        "<th>Name</th>"  +
         "<th>end_date</th>"  +
          "<th> time</th>"  +
           "<th> apply</th>"  +
    "  </tr>  "+
  "  </thead>"+

    " <tbody>  "    +
      '<tr class="light">' +

    "<td>"+this['id']  +" </td>" +

    "<td> "+this['name']+" </td>" +
      "<td> "+this['end_date']+" </td>" +
       "<td> "+this['time']+"</td>" +

     "<td><a onclick="+ 'location.href="../index.php?id="'+this['id']+'";"'+
       "a>Apply</a></td> "+


     "</tr>"+

  "  </tbody>        "+

    "</tr> "+
    " </tbody>"+
    "</table>");
});

});
}
```

Comment: show more context (html/js code)

Comment: Seems to me that your problem is that it is already firing the default action. you will need to prevent this then force the redirect manually.

Comment: What is wrong with just using "href"? <a href="../index.php?id='+this.id+'"> ?

Comment: May be better to create a function like function nextPage(id); and do the window.location there... Or just add it to the href

Comment: every think else works perfectly my problem only with this line of code. Just passing the id value. By the way if I remove this code ** this['id'] ** it works well and if i remove this code **../index.php?id= **  it works well as well but the problem is only when i try to pass to another page with value.

Comment: @Ali show us the rest of your code, its hard for us to tell what is going on here with this snippet

Comment: @NickDelaney I have edited the code, please have a look

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest this is the code of this page

Answer (score 1):

`id="'+this['id']+'";"` gives `id="whateverid"`
remove that quotation mark around your id like
`id='+this['id']+';"`